# How to show that $x^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\leq \frac{1}{p}x+\frac{1}{q}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $p,q>1$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $x\in[0,1]$. I would like to show that $x^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\leq \frac{1}{p}x+\frac{1}{q}$.

I tried to rewrite both sides of the inequality just involving $p$ or just involving $q$ but that didn't help me. Any hints how to prove the inequality?

Comment: Did you tried differentiating?

Comment: @HwChu How does that help? Differentiate for $x$ gives $\frac{1}{p}$ on the right side and $\frac{x^{\frac{1}{p}-1}}{p}=\frac{x^{\frac{-1}{q}}}{p}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{q}}p}$ for the left side, right?

Comment: @mathstackuser You should add these details into your question in order to reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{p}x+\frac{1}{q}-x^{1/p}$$ then $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p}x^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$$

Comment: Can you explain me how that helps? It Looks like a nice approach as I don't have to use other inequalities

Comment: It is equivalent to prove that $f(x) \geq 0$ when $x \in [0,1]$. By differentiating you can know there the maximum/minimum is, so you know the critical values to test $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh ok, so $f'(x)=0$ gives me $x=1$ and checking the second derivative, I see that this is a minimum. Then I see $f(1)=0$ and as $x=1$ is the minimum, we have $f(x)\geq 0$? But where do I use that $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: I think you just cannot define $x^{1/p}$ in general for $x<0$.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But what is about $x>1$?

Comment: I think you made a good point. Seems to hold as well for $x>1$.

Answer (score 10):

[Bernoulli's inequality:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) $(1+x)^r \leqslant 1+rx$ for $x \geqslant -1$ and $r \in [0,1]$.

Therefore: $~\displaystyle x^{\tfrac{1}{p}} \leqslant 1+\frac{1}{p}(x-1) = \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}(x-1) = \frac{1}{p}x+\frac{1}{q}.$

Comment: Very nice alternative!

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality, always useful. (+1) nice.

Answer (score 5):

We have that

$$ x^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\le \frac{1}{p}x+\frac{1}{q}\iff \frac1p \log x +\frac1q \log 1 \le \log \left(\frac1p x+\frac1q \right)$$

then recall that $\log$ function is concave and refer to [**Jensen's inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jensen%27s_Inequality) .

Answer (score 2):

By the weighted AM-GM inequality with $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{p}$, $x_1 = x$, $\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{q}$, $x_2 = 1$, we have
$$x^{1/p} \cdot 1^{1/q} \le \frac{1}{p} \cdot x + \frac{1}{q} \cdot 1.$$

Comment: That's also very nice!